# How can I hide Fiddler's tunnel-to requests?

Tags: fiddler

I've already read [*this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142802/hide-tunnel-to-sessions) (*very old one*) aboud how to hide "tunnel to" sessions in fiddler.

The answer was :

> Try the menu option `Rules` -> `Hide Connects`

Well , I'm  using Fiddler 4 , And already checked the settings :

[image]

But still — ( even after restart)  I see many "Tunnel To" requests :

[image]

**Question:**

How can I hide the "Tunnel To" requests in fiddler 4 ?

Comment: You can filter requests by host. Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746540/filtering-fiddler-to-only-capture-requests-for-a-certain-domain